# Can't get mongoose.js to expire old documents at the right time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_date_SchemaDate-expires I can expire old documents by adding an 'expires' attribute to a mongoose schema. The documents do get removed, when I use the code below, but after around 4 minutes instead of 10 (I've also tried with much higher numbers and e.g. the number 600 instead of '10m').

Any help is appreciated.

**Versions:**
mongoose: 3.8.12
MongoDB: 2.4.9

```
// models.js --------------------------------------------------------

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var signupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    token: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date, expires: '10m'}
});

signupSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.createdAt = Date.now();
    next();
});

mongoose.model('Signup', signupSchema);


// user.js (the code below is in a route) ---------------------------

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var SignupModel = mongoose.model('Signup');

var newSignup = new SignupModel({
    email: 'a@a.a',
    token: 'token'
});

newSignup.save(function(err, signup) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Is this code running on the same machine as the MongoDB server?

Comment: Yes it is. Also, the MongoDB's clock and mongoose's both run on UTC it seems.